# How to update Sharepoint list using SSIS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sharepoint, ssis

I am using SSIS to transfer data from MS SQl server as data source and Sharepoint list as data destination. Now, I need to fire an update command on the sharepoint list. Please guide me to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

See http://sqlsrvintegrationsrv.codeplex.com/releases/view/17652

Comment: Hi apul, thanks for the reply. I still could not understand how to update the list. I have inserted the data from sql to sharepoint list. The "ID" columnin sharepoint list is : I believe autogenerated, so i could not map it to anything. How do I update then....